# How can I search only all of the lemmas in a different module (in Coq)?

Tags: coq

I usually import QArith.

If I write

```
Search "max" "id".
```

Then I can see something like this:

```
Pos.max_id: forall n : positive, Pos.max n n = n
N.max_id: forall n : N, N.max n n = n
Nat.max_id: forall n : nat, Nat.max n n = n
Z.max_id: forall n : Z, Z.max n n = n
```

If I write

```
Search "Pos" "max".
```

Then nothing appears.

How can I search another (included?) library (or module) 's lemma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `inside` keyword: `Search "max" "id" inside Pos.` gives you exactly one answer, `Pos.max_id`. If you wish to exclude a module/library, you can use the `outside` keyword instead. `Search` is a very useful command to master, and there is a lot to it, you might want to look at the full [documentation](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.Search) to learn more about it!